# How to properly map Entity Framework entities to DTO and vice-versa?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapping, automapper, mapper

In the data access level, I have defined such an entity:

```cs
public class Instagram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? StateData { get; set; }
    public string? TwoFactorLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public string? ChallengeLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;

    public Proxy? Proxy { get; set; }
    public int? ProxyId { get; set; }

    public List<Work>? Works { get; set; }
}
```

At the abstraction level, there is such a DTO:

```cs
public class InstagramDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? StateData { get; set; }
    public string? TwoFactorLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public string? ChallengeLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public UserDto? User { get; set; }
    public ProxyDto? Proxy { get; set; }
}
```

Did I form the DTO correctly? It maps well to one side (from EF to DTO), but the problem is reverse mapping. I do it like this:

```cs
 CreateMap<InstagramDto, Instagram>()
            .ForMember(x => x.UserId,
                expression => expression.MapFrom((dto, _) => dto.User?.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.User, expression => expression.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Proxy,
                expression => expression.MapFrom((dto, _) => dto.Proxy?.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.Proxy, expression => expression.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Instagram, InstagramDto>();
```

That is, InstagramDto must have UserDTO and ProxyDto so that I can correctly map the entity from DTO to ef. At the same time, the user may have some other navigation properties that are not involved when receiving Instagram. This means that I cannot update the User, as its navigation properties are not loaded in this situation. Is this the right approach or would it be better to do so:

```cs
 public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? StateData { get; set; }
    public string? TwoFactorLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public string? ChallengeLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public int ProxyId { get; set; }
```